# Java - Finding minimum number

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

The following code is supposed to read through some numbers and put ' <== Smallest number' next to the smallest. What's my problem here? It doesn't seem to be working! Every time it seems to assign the wrong number as the minimum.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayex1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            int num = input.nextInt();

            numbers.add(num);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {


            if (numbers.get(findMin(numbers)) == i) { // If the 'smallest' index value is equal to i.

                System.out.println(numbers.get(i) + " <== Smallest number");

            } else {

                System.out.println(numbers.get(i));

            }

        }

    }

    public static int findMin(ArrayList<Integer> n) {

        int min = 0; // Get value at index position 0 as the current smallest.

        for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++) {

            if (n.get(i) < min) {

                min = i;

            }

        } 

        return min;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if (numbers.get(findMin(numbers)) == i) { // If the 'smallest' index value is equal to i.
> ```

By calling `numbers.get()` you fetch the value of the slot at `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `min` in `findMin()` is actually the index of the minimum number in `n`.
Change this:

```
if (n.get(i) < min)
```

to:

```
if (n.get(i) < n.get(min))
```

Store the return value of `findMin()` before entering the `for` loop:

```
final int min_idx = findMin(numbers);
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
    if (min_idx == i) { // If the 'smallest' index value is equal to i.
        System.out.println(numbers.get(i) + " <== Smallest number");
    } else {
        System.out.println(numbers.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You see the unexpected behavior because you don't obey the contract for [`List.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29). The method expects an **index** as argument and returns you the **value**. You should not compare the value returned by `get()` to an index.

Also, in your `findMin()` method you should initialize `min` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection sort method for sorting an list. [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

After the sort first element will be the smallest one

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved, working sample (though without the Scanner inputs for easy testing):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(7);
    numbers.add(3);

    int minIndex = findMin(numbers);
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        if(minIndex == i){ // If the 'smallest' index value is equal to i.
            System.out.println(numbers.get(i) + " <== Smallest number");
        }else{
            System.out.println(numbers.get(i));
        }
    }
}

public static int findMin(ArrayList<Integer> n){
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // Get value at index position 0 as the current smallest.
    int minIndex = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++){
        if(n.get(i) < minValue){
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```

There was some confusion as to if the findMin method returned the minimum value, or the minimum index.  It now returns the minimum index.  findMin is also now called only once, not for every iteration in the loop, which is a little cleaner (and slightly faster).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n.get(i) < min)
```

should be:

```
if (n.get(i) < n.get(min))
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/m4adp)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the following code and it will work for sure.

```
**if (numbers.get(findMin(numbers)) == numbers.get(i))** 
{ // If the 'smallest' index value is equal to i.               
   System.out.println(numbers.get(i) + " <== Smallest number");              
}

and 

public static int findMin(ArrayList<Integer> n) 
{         
  int min = 0; // Get value at index position 0 as the current smallest.          
  for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++) 
  {             
    **if (n.get(i) < n.get(min))**
    {                  
      min = i;              
    }         
  }          
  return min;     
}
```